# Generating a mathematical model of a pattern

Tags: algorithm, math

Does there exist some algorithm that allows for the creation of a mathematical model given an inclusive set?

I'm not sure I'm asking that correctly... Let me try again...

Given some input set...

```
int Set[] = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 };
```

Does there exist an algorithm that would be able to deduce the pattern evident in the set? In this case being...

```
Set[x] = x^2
```

The only way I can think of doing something like this is some GA where the fitness is how closely the generated model matches the input set.

Edit:

I should add that my problem domain implies that the set is inclusive. Meaning, I am finding the closest possible function for the set and not using the function to extrapolate beyond the set...

Comment: I think this would be better on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, because { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, -1, 75, pi, ... }  is just as "valid" a set as { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, ...}.  You need to know the closed form solution you are expecting, and then try to match it to a given set.

Comment: @mbeckish Agreed. For simple sets like the above one provided, you could just calculate the square root and see a linear relationship, or calculate the inverse-nth-root, etc. You can also apply a Fourier transform and search for peaks to determine if there are periodic occurrences. Without any information on the type of patterns you're expecting, the best you can do is apply multiple methods and see if any provide a useful correlation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are infinitely many answers to any set you give. For example there exists a polynomial of Degree 6 that hits all of those points in your example set.

Comment: @Alex Dead on. There are also infinitely many finite Fourier transform coefficient sets that generate the same set as a sum of sinusoids.

Comment: If you really need this functionality in a program, then make HTTP requests to [http://oeis.org/](http://oeis.org/) and parse the results.

Comment: On the other hand, there are countless quiz books that that will ask for the seventh term in the series and every 5th grader of certain caliber will answer 49 and the teacher will mark that correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of [curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) might be a reasonable place to start looking. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for - it won't really identify the pattern so much as just produce a function which follows the pattern as closely as possible.

As others have mentioned, for a simple set there can easily be infinitely many such functions, so something like this may be what you want, rather than exactly what you have described in your question.

Wikipedia seems to indicate that the [Gauss-Newton algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Newton_algorithm) or the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) might be a good place to begin your research.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the OP is asking for. This fits a generic function nicely to a set of data, but that would work for any data set in general where we force a specific type of function to fit an arbitrary data set. I think the OP is asking how to do automated pattern analysis to determine the nature of the sequence without knowing the generating function a priori.

Comment: I think you are right - although as you and others have mentioned doing precisely what he describes in his question may well be fundamentally impossible, so this may still be of interest.

Comment: Good point. This does point out the issue of infinite possible answers, so it's perfectly valid. Plus one :)

Answer (score 3):

A mathematical argument explaining why, in general, this is impossible:

- There are only countably many computer programs that can be written at all.
- There are uncountably many infinite sequences of integers.
- Therefore, there are infinitely many sequences of integers for which no possible computer program can generate those sequences.

Accordingly, this is impossible in the general case. Sorry!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if the given data fits some polynomial function, you compute successive differences until you reach a constant. The number of differences to reach the constant is the degree of the polynomial.

```
 x |   1     2     3     4
 y |   1     4     9    16
y' |      3     5     7
y" |         2     2
```

Since y" is 2, y' is 2x + C<sub>1</sub>, and thus y is x<sup>2</sup> + C<sub>1</sub>x + C<sub>2</sub>. C<sub>1</sub> is 0, since 2×1.5 = 3. C<sub>2</sub> is 0 because 1<sup>2</sup> = 1. So, we have y = x<sup>2</sup>.

So, the algorithm is:

- Take successive differences.
- If it does not converge to a constant, either resort to curve fitting, or report the data is insufficient to determine a polynomial.
- If it does converge to a constant, iteratively integrate polynomial expression and evaluate the trailing constant until the degree is achieved.